# Parse xml from url. Exception

Tags: android, xml

I need to get some info from URL("http://someurl.com/file.xml").
Info in tags - "name", "surname".

How can I do that ?

I know I must using AsyncTask for internet connection.

I trying using XMLPullParser in AsyncTask, but I get exception "IndeOutOfBound"

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        String name;

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... uri) {
                try {
                    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                    xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(
                            getUrlData("http://someurl.com/file.xml")));

                    while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                        if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                            if (xpp.getName().equals("name")) {
                                name=xpp.getAttributeValue(0);
                            }
                        }
                        xpp.next();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                }

} catch (IOException e) {
        //Handle problems..
        }
        return null;
        }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        "name="+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

}

Comment: Hi - did you get this resolved?  I was guessing your XML looked something like `<name>Joe Blow</name>`.  Just a guess (based on this information you provided).  But such an element has no "attributes", and would cause an "indexOutOfBounds" exception if you tried calling "xpp.getAttributeValue()" on it.  Q: Did you find the problem?  Q: Do the links in my response below help?

Comment: You are right man! Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the XML in "file.xml".

I suspect the error is here:

```
 ...
 if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
   if (xpp.getName().equals("name")) {
     name=xpp.getAttributeValue(0);  // <- Does your"<name>" tag have any attributes???
```

Here are some tutorials on Android XML processing:

- http://www.javatpoint.com/android-XMLPullParser-tutorial
- http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/download/unpacked/doc/quick_intro.html
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html

In particular, note the use of `getText()` to fetch element content.

Comment: Yeah, man! Many thanks! I was very tired and very sleepy.. You are right about my tag "<name>" doesn't have attributes and I need text of this tag)